# Frontpage modules appear on article pages

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a very weird problem with a JS Jobs installation on Joomla 3.2.3.

http://bartenders4hire.net/index.php

I'm using some modules on the main page: new jobs, new resumes and jobs by city and when i click on a link within the modules the info will show up at the bottom of the front page, still showing all the modules. Obviously this is not the desired effect. I need to have those modules to be shown only on the front page.

I'm using a theme by rockettheme, already tried to adjust settings on the back end, but without any solution. Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: sorry, i clicked to fast. Here the link to the site  http://bartenders4hire.net/index.php - click on BARTENDER within the new job module

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721430/home-page-modules-showing-on-articles-in-joomla/9730770#9730770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Articles without menu items are shown in the home page template by default. One solution is to create a hidden menu (simply an menu that's not published via a module) and create links to your articles in it. You can also create blog layouts to account for entire categories of articles in the same manner.

[More info from RocketTheme](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/general-discussion/162142-why-are-my-readmore-links-opening-inside-the-frontpage)

Comment: well, this seem to work for articles, but how would i adjust this to the modules?

Comment: Doesn't matter where the link resides. The resulting page is rendered in the same fashion.

Comment: sorry for being stupid. I still don't understand this. As example, what menu item would i create for this link http://bartenders4hire.net/index.php/component/jsjobs/jsjobs/viewjob/job-bartender-1/nav-15?Itemid=101 this is the output when i click on the word bartender on the homapage module

Comment: What type of page is that? Does it have an article in it? Link to that.

Comment: there is no page - it goes to the output within the jsjobs module http://bartenders4hire.net/index.php/component/jsjobs/jsjobs/viewjob/job-bartender-1/nav-15?Itemid=101 you can see it when you go to the homepage http://bartenders4hire.net/index.php and click on bartender inside the newest jobs module

Comment: please note that this module publishes new jobs as they arrive, so i can't create a link to each of them manually

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately the JED appears down at the moment. What menu item types are available for JSJobs? Try creating menu items to whatever you can.

Comment: i just created a menu with all jsjobs items, published it temporary at the footer. But it still gives me the same error - showing all front page modules

Comment: As I said, there's no need to publish the menu. I'm afraid that I'm out of ideas. If you care to send me admin credentials I'll take a quick look for anything I'm missing.

Comment: can you send me your email? i don't want to post the admin credentials here :)

Comment: JED is back online - would this do the trick? http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Comment: What you might want is to make custom positions in the homepage only but putting a condition into the index.php.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit, because i don't understand what you mean